# Sub Select into LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, subquery

I am rather new to LINQ and I wrote a query in SQL that I am not quite sure how to convert to a LINQ statement. What I have causes a syntax error on the MAX(), probably because MAX() cannot operate on a datetime value

Any help is appreciated.

**SQL**

```
select COUNT(distinct Club) as total
FROM GCClubData 
where NCBClub = 0 
and Date = (select max(Date) from GCClubData)
```

**LINQ**

```
var db = new EFContext();
var data = db.GCClubDatas.Where(x => x.Date.Equals(db.GCClubDatas.Max().Date) && !x.NCBClub);
```

Comment: Well your `Max(x.Date)` should be `Max(y => y.Date)`... you've got to provide a way of getting a date from any element in the sequence.

Comment: You can take a look at LinqPad (http://www.linqpad.net/) this tool can convert SQL to Linq statements. This is a very good way to learn linq if you're familiar to SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db = new EFContext();
var maxDate = db.GCClubDatas.Max(x => x.Date);
var data = db.GCClubDatas.Where(x => x.Date == maxDate && !x.NCBClub);
```

Comment: Why are you going out of your way to pull the `Max` call out of the query, thus actively preventing the query provider from executing a single query, and instead forcing it to execute two?

Answer (score 0):

This will be more efficient in terms of database hits:

```
db.GCClubDatas.Where(x => x.Date == db.GCClubDatas.Max(y => y.Date) && x.NCBClub == 0);
```

Comment: It is but your syntax is wrong (duplicate lambdas). Try:  var data = db.GCClubDatas.Where(x => x.Date.Equals(db.GCClubDatas.Max(y => y.Date)) && !x.NCBClub);